# Run script in rc.local not as root

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, rc.local

I want to launch python script on boot, but rc.local launches it as root, which causes error in my python module. Is it possible to make it run as non root? Instead of `nohup python /home/pi/script.py &` maybe I could use something which says it to use my non root user?

Comment: A different option: use `crontab` and use `@reboot` instead of the time parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
su - pi -c 'nohup python /home/pi/script.py' &
```

See [su(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html)

Comment: I tried - now even nohup.out file isnt created

Comment: Did you look in /home/pi?